# how to check whether two directories differ (no file list)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash-scripting

I'd like to get binary information whether two directories differ or not.
I don't want to list different files. Just binary result that can be used in "if" statement. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try

```
 if diff -q DIR1 DIR2
```

If that is still too verbose

```
if diff -q DIR1 DIR2 > /dev/null
```

Comment: Ok! With option -r works great